# Incomplete Fruit Salad

Tags: pattern, rebus

**1 fruit is missing, are you able to find it?**
[image]

Comment: Did you make this puzzle, or where did you get it from?

Comment: i made this puzzle

Comment: What is the third fruit called?

Comment: That's a jackfruit

Comment: Orange or Watermelon?

Comment: @PeymanMohamadpour no answer intended :)

Comment: Make it an answer, the comments are not meant for this

Comment: This seems to be a "guess what I am thinking" puzzle.  Multiple solutions would work but we have to find out which one you thought of.

Comment: By the way, the question is tagged "rebus".  Is it actually a rebus?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, i asked someone what to use as tag and that's what I've been told

Comment: Hi I see that my question is closed and considered too broad. I would like to try to reopen it again. 

Here was my idea: Besides the pattern A,B,J,K (two pairs of consecutive letters) there was another pattern; Apple has core/kernel, banana hasn't, Jackfruit has and Kiwi hasn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building off of [Logan's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/125978):

The missing fruit is

> [**kiwifruit**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwifruit) (also known as **kiwi**)

Reasoning:

> We can think of this puzzle in analogy format (apple : banana :: jackfruit : ?).
>
>  Some of the analogues we see include:
>
>  1) **Cross sections**: Apples and jackfruits have prominent cores and seeds, whereas bananas and kiwis have very small seeds scattered around the center.
>
>  2) **Words/letters**: The letters b and k follow a and j in the alphabet, and both jackfruit and kiwifruit have "fruit" in their names.
>
>  3) **Colors**: Perhaps a bit of a stretch, but both apples and jackfruits can come in red (red apple, Thai red jackfruit) and green colors (green apple, standard jackfruit), while both bananas and kiwifruits can come in green (unripe banana, standard kiwi) and yellow colors (ripe banana, golden kiwi).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is

> Blueberry?
>
>  I am thinking colour rather than fruit.

Comment: Blueberry is also not the intended answer, but good idea

Answer (score 1):

Is it kiwi? I think it might be in alphabet order. A for Apple then B for Banana. But, the next one is a jackfruit after j is k. So, kiwi?

Comment: You're on the right track, but there's another reason why it might be kiwi

Comment: Is it because the colors of the fruition the inside are different from the outside?

Comment: If you'd like a more robust reasoning for this particular fruit, consider [this sport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snooker#Scoring)...

Comment: No it's not, colors don't matter

Comment: Are you sure colors don't matter? In snooker the colors go red yellow green then brown. That's why it's kiwi...actually coconuts are brown.

Comment: @LoganSweeney yes I'm sure colors don't matter

Comment: Can you maybe add a hint? Well, probably not today though because you just posted this.

Comment: Apples and jackfruits have something that bananas don't have

Comment: apples and jackfruits have prominent seeds and cores, whereas bananas and kiwis only have small seeds?

also kiwi can technically be called kiwifruit, going along with the "fruit" suffix

is the puzzle idea that it's an analogy? like apple : banana :: jackfruit : kiwifruit

Comment: @azi the puzzle is tagged with 'rebus'.